# How to round 8.475 to 8.48 in C (rounding function that takes into account representation issues)? Reducing probability of issue

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding

I am trying to round 8.475 to 8.48 (to two decimal places in C). The problem is that 8.475 internally is represented as 8.47499999999999964473:

```
double input_test =8.475;    
printf("input tests: %.20f, %.20f \n", input_test, *&input_test);
```

gives:

```
input tests: 8.47499999999999964473, 8.47499999999999964473
```

So, if I had an ideal round function then it would round 8.475=8.4749999... to 8.47. So, internal round function is no appropriate for me. I see that rounding problem arises in cases of "underflow" and therefore I am trying to use the following algorithm:

```
double MyRound2( double * value) {
  double ad;
  long long mzr; 
  double resval;

  if ( *value < 0.000000001 )
    ad = -0.501; 
  else
    ad = 0.501;

  mzr = long long (*value);
  resval = *value - mzr;
  resval= (long long( resval*100+ad))/100;

  return resval;
}
```

This solves the "underflow" issue and it works well for "overflow" issues as well. The problem is that there are valid values x.xxx99 for which this function incorrectly gives bigger value (because of 0.001 in 0.501). How to solve this issue, how to devise **algorithm that can detect floating point representation issue and that can round taking account this issue?** Maybe C already has such clever rounding function? Maybe I can **select different value for constant ad - such that probability of such rounding errors goes to zero** (I mostly work with money values with up to 4 decimal ciphers).

I have read all the popoular articles about floating point representation and I know that there are tricky and unsolvable issues, but my client do not accept such explanation because client can clearly demonstrate that Excel handles (reproduces, rounds and so on) floating point numbers without representation issues.

Comment: Your client is misinformed. Show him [this article by Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/78113). There are others. You need to convert to a decimal radix and do your rounding in that. If it's money it should be decimal radix in the first place.

Comment: Never use floats for money. Use `int` and calculate in millicent or something like that. Also the internal representation is in binary and things like `0.1` cannot be represented exactly in binary, it is like `1/3` in decimal.

Comment: Multiply your money values until there *are* no decimal points in there. (Instead of 8.59 dollar, use 859 cent. You get the idea.) If that means your values exceed the range available in your integer types, use some bignum library. **Never** use floats for monetary calculations (precisely *because* floats are silently imprecise).

Comment: @DevSolar, That is a good solution, but bear in mind that some currencies (e.g. Tunisian Dinar have 3 digits after the decimal separator). Even worse than that is Bitcoin, which has 8.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Doesn't change my advice. Shift the decimal point out of there, use bignum libs if necessary. I had the experience of working with software that did shift millions of Euros. You just *do not* want rounding errors in there.

Comment: You might use the C-library function `round` (round(precision * value)). However you may have another problem: A "correct" monetary calculation like "n * a + m * b" might be "round(n * a) + round(m * b)".

Answer (score 6):

(The C and C++ standards are intentionally flexible when it comes to the specification of the `double` type; quite often it is IEEE754 64 bit type. So your observed result is platform-dependent).

You are observing of the pitfalls of using floating point types.

Sadly there isn't an "out-of-the-box" fix for this. (Adding a small constant pre-rounding just pushes the problem to other numbers).

Moral of the story: **don't** use floating point types for money.

Use a special currency type instead or work in "pence"; using an integral type instead.

By the way, Excel *does* use an IEEE754 double precision floating point for its number type, but it also has some clever tricks up its sleeve. Essentially it tracks the joke digits carefully and also is clever with its formatting. This is how it can evaluate 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 exactly. But even it will get money calculations wrong sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

For financial calculations, it is better to work in base-10 to avoid represenatation issues when going to/from binary. In many countries, financial software is even legally required to do so. Here is one library for IEEE 754R Decimal Floating-Point Arithmetic, have not tried it myself:
http://www.netlib.org/misc/intel/

Also note that working in decimal floating-point instead of fixed-point representation allows clever algoritms like the Kahan summation algorithm, to avoid accumulation of rounding errors. A noteworthy difference to normal floating point is that numbers with few significant digits are not normalized, so you can have e.g both 1*10^2 and .1*10^3.

An implementation note is that one representation in the std uses a binary significand, to allow sw implementations using a standard binary ALU.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one: Define some threshold. This threshold is the distance to the next multiple of 0.005 at which you assume that this distance could be an error of imprecision. Execute appropriate methods if it's within that distance and smaller. Round as usual and at the end, if you detected that it was, add 0.01.

That said, this is only a work around and somewhat of a code smell. If you don't need too much speed, go for some other type than float. Like your own type that works like

class myDecimal{ int digits; int exponent_of_ten; } with value = digits * E exponent_of_ten

Answer (score 1):

I am not trying to argument that using floating point numbers to represent money is advisable - it is not! but sometimes you have no choice... We do kind of work with money (life incurance calculations) and are forced to use floating point numbers for everything including values representing money.

Now there are quite some different rounding behaviours out there: round up, round down, round half up, round half down, round half even, maybe more. It looks like you were after round half up method.

Our round-half-up function - here translated from Java - looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cfloat>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double value = 8.47499999999999964473;
  double result = value * pow(10, 2);
  result = nextafter(result + (result > 0.0 ? 1e-8 : -1e-8), DBL_MAX);
  double integral = floor(result);
  double fraction = result - integral;
  if (fraction >= 0.5) {
    result = ceil(result);
  } else {
    result = integral;
  }
  result /= pow(10, 2);
  cout << result << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

where `nextafter` is a function returning the next floating point value after the given value - this code is proved to work using C++11 (AFAIK the `nextafter` is also available in boost), the result written into the standard output is 8.48.